# Select2 deactivates after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

i've activated the Select2 plugin for all my select elements in my layout page (to apply it to the whole application)

```
<script> $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2()
```

But after the ajax call, select2 applied to all select elements deactivates, how to fix this? I want to keep select2 active forever. Thanks!

Comment: add  `$('select').select2()` in `ajax` `success`

Comment: Where is the part of your code that includes the AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, I realise, and it's hard to know if your problem is exactly the same as mine, but I just came across a similar issue.

I was adding new `select` controls to my page using Ajax and then initialising Select2 on the newly-added `select` controls in the `success` callback. What I found was that whenever this happened, existing `select` controls on the page would cease to be modified by Select2.

Eventually I discovered that the cause of the issue was that the dynamically-added `select` controls all had the same `id`. This seems to break Select2, though in fairness there should never be more than one element on a page with a particular `id` at any given time.

You can see the behaviour illustrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/z3tdLa8c/).

The solution was just to ensure that I set a unique value for the `id` attribute of each `select` element that I added when the Ajax call was successful.